# IE9 Javascript generated table

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

Hi I have a problem only in IE9

I have a Javascript loop the generates a table first

```
   var TABLE = widget.body.getElementsByClassName('classroom')[0];
   var TBODY = widget.createElement('tbody');

        //generate rows & Cells, 10 x 10
        var cID = 0;
        for (var r=0; r<10; r++) {
            var TR = widget.createElement('tr'); 
              for (var c=0; c<10; c++) {  
                    var TD = widget.createElement('td');
                    //TD.id="c"+cID;
                    TD.setAttribute("class",'c'+cID);
                    TD.setAttribute("id",'c'+cID);
                    TD.setAttribute("style","width:90px;");
                    TD.setAttribute("style","height:90px;");
                    cID++;
                    TR.appendChild(TD);
                }
                TBODY.appendChild(TR);
         }
         TABLE.appendChild(TBODY);
```

Which works fine

it's then calls this another function to populate the table.

this is just a snippet the functions huge!

```
var cell_class = cell.toString();   // it gets the cell from another loop say 'c1'
var TCell = widget.body.getElementsByClassName(cell_class)[0]; 
TCell.innerHTML="<a href='#'>image</a>"; // it fails at this point 'null or undefined'
```

in the HTML I have

```
<table id="table1" class="classroom">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col width="90" height="70"/>
                        <col width="90" height="70"/>
                        <col width="90" height="70"/>
                        <col width="90" height="70"/>
                        <col width="90" height="70"/>
                        <col width="90" height="70"/>
                        <col width="90" height="70"/>
                        <col width="90" height="70"/>
                        <col width="90" height="70"/>
                        <col width="90" height="70"/>
                    </colgroup>
                </table>
```

it works if I add a static table to the HTML but I want it dynamic.

This works in all the current browsers apart from IE9

Can anyone Help

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you don't use jQuery templates or handlebars (or any other templating library for that matter.) to help you with dynamic generation?

I think the issue with IE is, it does not create the TBODY element by default unless you have it in markup. I think Other browsers create that element implicitly if it is not present.

Try adding a tbody element manually in markup.

Comment: I've just tried targeting the tBody by class and still the same.
when you say "Add tbody element manually in markup" Where do you mean?

Comment: What is this widget class you are using? I would highly recommend using a templating library for this. That could reduce lot of pain for you.

Comment: I'm working within a framework called Frog its basically a CMS. You can also build Javascript widgets.
You just have to put widget in front of your function. Which can be a pain hence not using external templates.